# How do I install AMIL without python?

Tags: python, xml, artificial-intelligence

So I've really been trying to get into AI recently, but I can't install Python (windows education) and I don't have admin rights. Which is a problem.

I have the portable version of python, from the .zip, which means I can't use pip. That to, due to admin restrictions, I can't use windows terminal.

So I do I install AMIL without python, because I've been struggling to.

Also, something totally different, what other languages should I use for AI? If you could answer that I would really appreciate it.

Thanks :)

Comment: you can use pip you just have to use it in usermode (i think `-U` ... maybe `-u`?)

Comment: @JoranBeasley In the python terminal?

Comment: no ... to a local folder /Lib  in the command shell (or bash terminal)

Comment: this question might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23888109/portable-python-cant-install-pip